# How to follow multiple threads that write to the same logfile

Tags: linux, tail

I have a python-process that uses 12 threads. All threads write to the same logfile.

I am following the output with `tail -f` but as you can imagine, the output is hard to read if you want to follow single processes.

There is [multitail](https://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/) to follow multiple logfiles. It does this by [sectioning the screen into nr-of-logfiles](https://www.tecmint.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/MultiTail-Two-Files-620x406.jpeg) and then shows each log in one window.

How can I follow multiple threads that write to the same logfile?

Comment: As an idea, you could add the thread id to your logging and do multiple tail -f | grep thread id.

Comment: Note you could follow multiple files by `tail -f /log/domains*/access.log`.

Comment: @JoãoGuitana instead of *multiple `tail -f`*, consider `tail -f | tee >(cmd1) >(cmd2) | cmd3`! Look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58559125/1765658)

Answer (score 1):

For this, I use `sed` and `stdbuf` (... and `bash` ;)

```
tail -f mylogfile | sed -une /mythread/p
```

Simpliest.

- `sed -u` ->  `--unbuffered`

  > ```
  > -u, --unbuffered
  >      load minimal amounts of data from the input files and flush the output buffers more often
  > ```
- `sed -n` -> `--quiet, --silent`

  > ```
  > -n, --quiet, --silent
  >      suppress automatic printing of pattern space
  > ```

Multiple:

```
tail -f mylogfile |
    stdbuf -i0 -o0 tee >(
        sed -une /thread 1/p >file1
      ) >(
        sed -une /thread 2/p >file2
      ) >(
        sed -une '/thread 3/s/.*/INSERT INTO l_t_3 VALUES (DEFAULT,\o47&\o47);/p' |
             someSqlclient
      ) | 
        sed -une /last thread/p >lastfile
```

Of course `file1` and others could be `fifo`, `file`, `unnamed fifo` and via `socat` or `nc`, a lot of other things...

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question correctly, you say : I have here a file, and I would like to know which piece of that file has been written by which thread of my program.

I'm afraid this is impossible : a process might lock a file, this causes a link between the file and the process, but there is no link between that file and any threads within that process. (Don't forget, once your process releases that lock, you won't find any relation anymore between the process and the file.)

As proposed by João, you might alter your process in order to add thread specific information to the mentioned file, but without altering your process, I'm afraid that what you're asking is impossible.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It's not what I mean: I have a logfile, that logfile has lines and on those lines is an indicator saying what thread has written that line. The issue is that it's hard to read. Ideally I am looking for a process that shows a line in subwindow 1 if thread 1 wrote the line, subwindow 2 if thread 2 wrote the line and so on.

Comment: Ah, ok, can't you do this combining a `tail -f` with a `grep`? Something like `tail -f logfile.log | grep <ThreadID> >logfile_<ThreadID>`, while you have another (sub)window with a `tail -f logfile_<ThreadID>`?